# How is Docker being used in VPS hosting?

Tags: security, vps, docker

I'm curious how Docker is being used to host VPS 's ?

e.g. 
I get that it's very fast to boot, but I've heard that security of Docker is not enough to keep people out of the main system... **How are companies securing Docker as VPS** (specifics)?

Also, I've tried to escalate to the main system w/o success, **how are people breaching Docker**?

**EDIT**

Apparently, Docker is not the solution for those who want to spin up an isolated environment for some user to bang on.... so my question would then transition to : 
**What are companies using that lets them spin up an isolated environment *quickly*?**

Comment: Docker isn't used to host VPSes. It's not designed for that.

Comment: Also, nice try, but still not on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen it in use for something like that, and it's certainly not recommended. They've made some significant improvements including automatic MCS labeling with SELinux for each Docker container, and greatly reducing the number of kernel capabilities granted to the Docker process. However, as Linux itself does not offer namespace isolation with all of its components there are potentially ways to break out of the containers. Lowering the permissions of the Docker container with the USER directive may further help reduce risk, but isn't a perfect solution. As there is no hypervisor running, you are making calls directly to the kernel, making the host vulnerable to local privilege escalation attacks. The bottom line is that the creators of Docker don't recommend this use, and I haven't seen anyone claiming they were doing this. Here are more details about some of the potential avenues of attack: http://opensource.com/business/14/9/security-for-docker

Comment: Thank you, that was very detailed. What are companies using for VPS then?

Comment: @RossTheBoss Xen. VPSes don't need to launch in a second or two like a Docker container does. No one minds a couple minutes wait to boot.

Comment: Interesting. So if I were to use Xen, there would be no way for a user to escalate outside of their vm (even if they are root)?

Comment: @RossTheBoss Given that Amazon uses it, I suspect it's fairly safe. That's not to say there can't be security holes - AWS and other Xen-based hosts had to patch a few months back for one - but that's true for any system.

Comment: @ceejayoz Wow, I had no idea Amazon used it. I imagine they did some additional development work as they generally seem to be pretty security conscious. I am going to have to ask around about that as I'm curious what they're doing with it.

Comment: @RossTheBoss Well, it's certainly much harder to do so when you're running something like Xen. There have been hypervisor vulnerabilities before, but they are seemingly discovered rarely. I can't say there isn't a way to do it with Xen at this time, I just know that Docker is considered to be more brittle in that respect because of the lack of a hypervisor.

Comment: Okay, so I've taken some time to learn differences between containers & vm's . ... it's kind of sad that containers don't care as much about the escalation attacks... from a computational stand point, they get rid of a tremendous amount of inefficiency (more dry, i mean). Thank you for everyone that contributed to this answer. Xen is a pretty cool tool